# Jackson Spring-boot test coverage

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jackson, generated-code

I'm developing a rest API on IntelliJ and I was wondering if there's a way to exclude Jackson generated classes from test coverage. Searching online I didn't find anything except a way to tell IntelliJ to exclude some packages, but I thought that the annotation @Generated would automatically exclude generated classes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which engine are you using for testing? The IntelliJ default one?

Comment: yes, i just realized that I can edit the run configuration and use Jacoco as coverage runner, now the coverage is 100%, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I finally found the solution: I changed the run configurations of my application

Run -> Edit configurations.. -> Modify options -> Specify alternative coverage runner -> I chose JaCoCo instead of IntelliJ -> Apply

Now the coverage is 100% because JaCoCo skips the classes with the @Generated annotation